# The code below is working fine in other browsers but not in IE .please help me out on this

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.panel_button").click(function() {
        $("div#panel").animate({
            height: "223px",
        }, "fast");

        $("div.panel_button").toggle();
    });

    $("div#hide_button").click(function() {
        $("div#panel").animate({
            height: "0px",
        }, "slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Format your code properly, and provide more information than "it doesn't work". Do you get JavaScript errors? What **does** happen (if it's nothing, see the previous question about JavaScript errors) and what **do you want/expect** to happen?

Comment: First post a real question, second add a fiddle, then someone can test live with your code. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

You've got trailing commas in your object literals. Change:

```
{height: "223px",}
// and
{height: "0px",}
```

To:

```
{height: "223px"}
// and
{height: "0px"}
```

(Commas *between* properties have - of course - always been required, but although other browsers have accepted the trailing comma for a while, and IE9 is cool with it, older IE didn't like it.)